# Incorporating navigation bar in UIViewController in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm using Xcode 4, but not Storyboards

We have a navigation controller instantiated in the app delegate.

When we create view controllers with Xibs the xibs are views that are the height of the iphone (without the navigation bar). Putting content in this area is deceptive as there is actually 44pt's less space (the height of the nav bar) which gets put there by the navigation controller.

Therefore how do we remove the room where the nav bar should be in interface builder?

I can click the view and then change the "top bar" to "navigation bar" which will work, but I cannot add bar button items to this navigation bar, which makes me think that this is not the correct way to do it.

Can anyone let me know what the best way to do this is?

Many thanks

Comment: Another reason why you should use storyboards.

Comment: I get stuck in storyboards when I have to programatically populate a UITableView - I'm not sure how to link dynamic content to new view controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you push your controller or use it to init the navigation controller, the navigation controller should take care of resizing at run time.  The area in IB where you set the top bar is under the heading "Simulated Metrics" and is meant to give you a preview of what your selected interface elements will do to your available display area.  The "Simulated" part is why you can't put items into that bar.

The real navigation bar should be configured wherever the navigation controller is defined, whether in code or a xib.

Comment: Damn, interface builder is rubbish - it makes ios development a weird mix of programatic and visual interfaces. So, if I want to add bar button items to a specific view controller's navigation bar I'll have to do it programatically? Psh.

Comment: The navigation bar belongs to the navigation controller rather than there being one to modify for each view controller.  The real problem is that you can't express conditional logic in IB.  (E.g. Can't tell the navigation controller to change buttons depending on which view controller is on top of its stack.)

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I thought there may be a way to connect a UINavigationController object to a UIViewController's `navigationController` property. But obviously not. I guess its because a UIViewController can be stand alone, or included in a navigation stack too.